# Fastboot devices returns list of question marks

Tags: android, terminal, command, adb, fastboot

I am trying to repair a Huawei Ascend P1 that was running a custom version of Cyanogenmod 12 and got locked in a bootloop. I am running custom recovery ClockworkMod however attempts to format, restore through the recovery, have all failed, the Dalvik Cache doesn't even wipe, /system doesn't wipe, nothing. Even the stock rom won't flash. I am instead attempting an alternative approach by attempting to flash the recovery to stock through fastboot, and there for the custom ROM back to stock firmware. I am running Ubuntu, and all though I have previously tried with Windows 10, I am getting the same errors on both operating systems. Fastboot and ADB have been fully installed and setup. The issue I am having is that when (on Ubuntu 15), I run `fastboot devices` nothing is returned. When I run `sudo fastboot devices`, the terminal returns:

```
timic@Home-PC:~$ sudo fastboot devices
????????????    fastboot
```

I have a feeling that its an issue with the drivers but when I was on Windows, I had the Huawei Drivers properly installed and still received question marks where I would expect to receive the serial number for the device. This means that any fastboot commands that I attempt to run returned a FAILED error. Any ideas on how to fix this issue, and if possible, how to repair the phone overall?

Comment: already you created the file "[/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/device.html)" ?

Comment: @kodamirmo Yes I have already created the file using Nano Text Editor, with the same results

Answer (score 0):

It's a cable fault. In my Redmi 3 on a cable from old Xperia P i've had question marks, 
replaced the cable to a newer cable from Redmi Note 2 and voila - the correct number displays instead of the question marks.